# using RestTemplate.exchange GET request vs posting URL in google chrome

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

Rest Template is used to create applications that consume RESTful Web Services. You can use the exchange() method to consume the web services for all HTTP methods.

Comment: Hello. I have trouble understanding the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome (or any browser) will send several extra HTTP headers along with the request, such as user agent, cookies, etc, by default. It'll also render any Javascript from the response as well as make extra requests for static assets such as CSS files, fonts, images, etc. Unclear what you mean by "url posting", but POST requests are typically only done on HTML forms.

RESTTemplate will only send headers and session data you've explicitly set, and will not evaluate any Javascript content in responses. It'll return the plaintext returned from the web server, and not request files linked within an HTML response.

An "image response" would be returned as bytes for both, potentially with a `Content-Type` header. RESTTemplate cannot "render" HTML `<img>` tags. Instead, you'd need to parse the `src` address, then make a new GET request for static assets